# How can I set the size and location of a window of an external application I call in Python on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, pywin32

I have been trying to automate some software and part of it requires that I use Python to start a couple of third-party applications. I would like to define where the windows of these applications spawn in and what the size of these windows are. I have tried using `subprocess` and `pywin32`, but I cannot seem to control the window size with either library. I have been trying to use `subprocess.STARTUPINFO()` and `win32process.STARTUPINFO()` and then defining the `dwX`, `dwXSize`, etc, but the application seems to totally ignore them. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Code using `subprocess`:

```py
import subprocess
import win32con
import win32gui
import ctypes
import time
 
wave = "C:\\Program Files\\LeCroy\\WaveStudio\\WaveStudio.exe"
 
startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
startupinfo.dwX = 100
startupinfo.dwy = 100
startupinfo.dwXSize = 400
startupinfo.dwYSize = 600
# startupinfo.dwFlags = win32con.STARTF_USEPOSITION | win32con.STARTF_USESIZE
subprocess.Popen(wave, startupinfo=startupinfo)
```

Code using `win32process`

```py
import win32con
import win32process
 
wave = "C:\\Program Files\\LeCroy\\WaveStudio\\WaveStudio.exe"
 
# Set the size and position of the window
startupinfo = win32process.STARTUPINFO()
startupinfo.dwX = 0
startupinfo.dwY = 0
startupinfo.dwXSize = 200
startupinfo.dwYSize = 300
startupinfo.dwFlags = win32con.STARTF_USEPOSITION | win32con.STARTF_USESIZE
 
# Create a new process with the specified path and window size/position
process_information = win32process.CreateProcess(
    None,
    wave,
    None,
    None,
    False,
    win32process.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,
    None,
    None,
    start
```